# Expressing n in terms of x, given x in terms of n

Tags: algebra

Using Wolfram Alpha, I tried finding solution of this:

If n(n - 1)/2 = x,then find value of n. Unfortunately, not getting value for n.

[image]

Comment: `Solve[n (n - 1)/2 == x, n]`

Comment: This means training in Wolfram language is a must for using Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha uses A.I. to parse inputs. It can interpret inputs many ways. Inputs provided using proper Mathematica syntax are recognized and processed successfully. My attempt at the same problem generated this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8HyZ.png) and I also checked that the `==` sign was not necessary either.

Comment: Suppose n will always be an integer. Then is there a way to get a different result. The solution derived with Solve[n (n - 1)/2 == x, n] is for real number n with surds.  With n(n-1)/2, we get the number of pairs when say number of candidates in an election n. For 2 candidates, number of pair 1, for 3 candidates, number of pairs 2, and so on.

Comment: Please start this query as a fresh post and describe the problem. Include any Mathematica code that you have tried so far. Due to parsing ambiguities (and perhaps for deeper technical reasons) Wolfram Alpha questions are considered off-topic on this forum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Wolfram Alpha questions are Off-topic. The site documentation reads: [Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: Questions on Wolfram Alpha).](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Some%20kinds%20of,Mathematica%20are%20okay).)

Answer (score 1):

Calling WolframAlpha from Mathematica

```
WolframAlpha["solve n(n-1)/2 = x for n"]
```

[image]